# I have a question about uploading a trained model to production on gcp

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, tensorflow-serving

I am trying to follow Google's directions to upload a trained model to the cloud.  It is just a portfolio-builder, and all I'm doing is mnist classification.  I am getting stuck right here:

[Web Link](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/reference/rest/v1/projects.models/create)

My question is, how is a model created with a gRPC request as per the above link?  I understand the basics of HTTP, but I'm obviously missing something as far as how this works.  Is the project name unique and that is how it is created in the string:

```
POST https://ml.googleapis.com/v1/{parent=projects/*}/models
```

Thanks so much for your help.

I've gone through HTTP and gRPC documentation, and I still don't understand how this works.

Here is the code they want me to run, but I'm obviously missing something about how this works.

```
POST https://ml.googleapis.com/v1/{parent=projects/*}/models
```

Answer (score 0):

The URI is using gRPC transcoding to provide both REST and gRPC endpoints.

If you're just using REST, this would be:

```
POST https://ml.googleapis.com/v1/projects/<YOUR PROJECT NAME>/models
```

where the the request body is an instance of a [Model](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/reference/rest/v1/projects.models#Model).